# Solve the trigonometric equation for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find $x$ $$\sin60 \sin30 \sin x=\sin50 \sin20 \sin(20-x)$$

$\frac{\sin(20^\circ-x)}{\sin x} = \cos 20^\circ-\sin20^\circ\cdot \cot x$, so we can easily find $x$.
But you write Cheva theorem, probably, there exists a geometric solution.

Comment: Ceva's theorem is trivially satisfied as $(60^°+20^°)+(50^°+30^°)+(20^°-x+x)=180^°$.

Comment: Is it related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469866/solve-sin12%c2%ba-sin24%c2%ba-sin84%c2%ba-x%c2%ba-sin30%c2%ba-sin30%c2%ba-sinx%c2%ba